# Mapinfo problem importing mid/mif

Tags: mapinfo, import

I am trying to import a mid/mif into MapInfo. I follow the usual routine of Table --> Import and select the correct mid/mif.

I get the following error:

(f:\FILENAME.mif:8) Found [(] while searching for [An identifier]

I have searched online and found no mention of this error. Any help?

Comment: What are the first ten lines of the `.mif` file?

Comment: Version 300

Charset "Neutral"

Delimiter ","

CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 79, "m", -2, 49, 0.9996012717, 400000, -100000

Columns 32

  average_elevation Float

  date Char(10)

  domestic Integer(10)

  domestic_area Integer(10)

  drawing_colour Char(8)

@CL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integer(10)` is not a valid MapInfo data type (at least not in the version you are using).
(Where did you get that file from?)

Replace that column type with either `Integer` or `Decimal(10, 0)`.

Comment: I have changed these values, but now lose a number of the polygons? I had edited the files in qGIS, would this have caused he problem? @Cl.

Comment: @DGraham From QGIS can you save the file as ShapeFile and then open the Shape file in MapInfo?

Comment: Saving as a shapfile takes a digit of some of the values?! So reduces down codes from six to five! @Cl.

Comment: Yeah, can't explain it, and is very annoying!@Cl.

Comment: Can't try it myself to confirm it works (and its a bit 'around the houses', but if you have a primary key in the data, would it be possible to select all of the columns EXCEPT the integer(10) column(s), save as a new layer and then export that to mid/mif for loading into MapInfo, then do a selection of primary key and the integer(10) column(s) and export as CSV.  Load both into MapInfo and then rejoin on primary key.

Comment: @DGraham Missing polygons are not related to the values of integer fields; it appears that the QGIS `.mid` exporter has multiple problems. I would have recommended ShapeFiles, too; are those missing digits from text or floating-point fields?

Comment: @Cl. I got there in the end, by missing out MapInfo all together and using the Table Manager function in qgis. I think the problem was in the original data set and by remaining in qgis throughout, it would not falter. Thanks for the help!